# Outlook Add-in: Office Initialization Problem and Blank Taskpane

Tags: reactjs, office-js, office-addins

I'm running a **react outlook addin desktop** locally using the node package `@microsoft/office-js`

I added the static files that are in `node_modules\@microsoft\office-js\dist` to `/assets/office-js` directory, and referenced it in the *taskpane.html* file:

```
<script src="/assets/office-js/office.js"></script>
```

This is my **index.tsx** file:

```
import App from "./components/App";
import { AppContainer } from "react-hot-loader";
import { initializeIcons } from "@fluentui/font-icons-mdl2";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@fluentui/react";
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

/* global document, Office, module, require */

initializeIcons();

let isOfficeInitialized = false;

const title = "Contoso Task Pane Add-in";

console.log(--index file--);

const render = (Component) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <ThemeProvider>
        <Component title={title} isOfficeInitialized={isOfficeInitialized} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById("container")
  );
};

/* Render application after Office initializes */
Office.onReady(() => {
console.log(--Office initialized--);
  isOfficeInitialized = true;
  render(App);
});

if ((module as any).hot) {
  (module as any).hot.accept("./components/App", () => {
    const NextApp = require("./components/App").default;
    render(NextApp);
  });
}
```

**The Taskpane is blank**. *"index file"* was logged, but **office wasn't initialized** (the callback function that is sent to `office.onReady()` wasn't called).

The console logged:

```
Uncaught Office Web Extension script library file name should be office.js or office.debug.js
```

What did I do wrong?